# Npm "ENOTFOUND error" while installing a package

Tags: node.js, npm

I would like to install a npm package and it shows me this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.your-registry.npme.io/npmrc failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.your-registry.npme.io
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

I tried to uninstall [fully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x) npm and node.js, and reinstall it and it still does not work.

Any Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command :

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Idk how you managed to change the default registry, but here's how you undo it :)

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to upvote and mark my answer as correct :)